# How do I auto-login on Jenkins when a page is not found?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using a Jenkins server to manage my pipelines, and some jobs have restricted access. If you try to access their URL while logged out, it says that the page is not found.

How can I get Jenkins to attempt to log me in before declaring the page does not exist?

P.S. I'm looking for solutions that don't include me logging in elsewhere manually before refreshing the page. I want to go straight from logged-out to logged in and accessing the right page, in one click. No additional actions. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you had logged into Jenkins with the "Remember me" option once, you would get auto-logged in the following times without having to do anything. This will remain the case until you manually logout. On the other hand if you want Jenkins to automatically log you in without you having logged in before even once, then it defeats the purpose of having authentication in the first place.

Are you trying to do some sort of automation (access a page using curl/selenium, etc..)? If so, some context would help.